# Scale material rather than UV

Tags: materials, uv

I'm using Blender to render furniture in a room. Each board of the furniture is its own object. When applying material for each board I have to scale UV to match the desired result. I need to scale UV of each board so the texture has the same scale on each board.

Is it possible to somehow remember the scale so I don't have to do it manually? In layman's term: I want to scale the texture not the UV.

However I would like to avoid unwrapping multiple objects at once because:

1. it's messy
2. when I add new object afterwards I have to repeat the process.

Thank you.

Comment: Usually, to preserve the scale over many different sized objects, you can use the _Object_ output in the _Texture Cooordinate_ node and specify an object which should be used. However this doesn't work with UVs... The only way I see how this could work is join all objects into one, and on unwrapping (depending on the method) check "Correct Aspect" to have all islands have the appropriate size compared to each other - but that's something you want to avoid.

Comment: Hi :). You need uniform *texel density*. [There are addons](https://mrven.gumroad.com/l/CEIOR) which can set specific density for UVs without repeated unwrapping. Practically indispensable in any archviz project :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a builtin addon called MagicUV that gives you a World Scale UV option.

[image: image reference]

[image: second reference]

the settings are remembered between uses so you can apply it again without worrying about them

This will scale your UVs to match the correct texture density.

Unfortunately scaling the texture in material individually is complicated. The simplest implementation of this would be

- ajust the scale of each object using `Properties`:`Workspacce`:`only origins`
- multiply the object scale with the UV scale for the texture coordinate in the material

so you could quickly manually ajust the texture scaling without messing with UVs

Comment: Hi :). Would you mind adding a bit of explanation about what this does? Thanks.

Comment: This scales your UV islands in a similar way to 'average island scale', but based on some constant value you can choose. The pivot point will use median.